# Simulating border-collapse in lists (no tables)

Tags: css, list, border

When I have 2 adjacent elements with borders, the borders are merged. With tables we have the border-collapse property for solving this.

I've tried omitting the border from one of the sides, but that works only for elements in the middle, the first and final element will miss a border.

Does somebody know a solution for list elements for example?

Comment: Did you mean: "the borders are *not* merged"?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

You can add a left and bottom border to the ul and drop it from the li.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TELK7/

html:

```
<ul>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two</li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
ul{
    border: 0 solid silver;
    border-width: 0 0 1px 1px;
}
li{
    border: 0 solid silver;
    border-width: 1px 1px 0 0;
    padding:.5em;
}
```

Answer (score 84):

Here's how I solved it: add a margin-left/-top of -1px to each li element. Then the borders really collapse without any tricks.

Comment: Yes, I think this is a very good and simple solution too, here is the jsfiddle for testing it: http://jsfiddle.net/NAezw/

Comment: This one is pretty sleek, when the boundaries of the `<li>`-tags do not join the border of the surrounding `<ul>`-tag.

Comment: I had to add padding of 2px on the parent ul, otherwise the borders at the very top or bottom sometimes didn't show. `<ul style="display:block;clear:both;width:100%;padding:2px">` and `<li style="float:left;width:215px;height:240px;border:1px solid black; margin-left:-1px;margin-top:-1px">`

Comment: In order to return list elements on starting offset (keeping the virtual border-collapse intact), one can for example use: `margin-left: -1px; margin-top: -1px; position: relative; top: 1px; left 1px;` It works in IE7 also.

Comment: I voted this answer because it's good for responsive websites and it's almost universal. I used it for links, without any lists involved. But you do need to "return" this 1px with some sort of a wrapper.

Comment: @user1862764 To avoid the first element to go up 1px use this: `ul:not(:first-child) li { margin-top: -1px; }`

Answer (score 12):

You can do this using CSS pseudo selectors:

```
li {
    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-right: none;
}

li:last-child {
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
}
```

This will clear the right hand border on all li elements except the last one in the list.

Comment: This is the best answer

Comment: This is a bad practice because if you have to do something with border on active or hover state then everything falls apart

Answer (score 4):

Little late to this party, but here's how to get a list item's **complete** border to change on hover.

First, just use (top and side) borders on the `li` elements, then give the last one a bottom border.

```
li:last-child {border-bottom:2px solid silver;}
```

Then, choose a hover border style:

```
li:hover {border-color:#0cf;}
```

Finally, use a sibling selector to change the *next* item's top border to match your hover item's hover border.

```
li:hover + li {border-top-color:#0cf;}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8umrq46g/

Answer (score 2):

Old thread, but I found another solution, and more important:

**YOU DON'T HAVE TO KNOW WHICH IS THE PARENT ELEMENT**

```css
li{
  border: 2px solid gray;
}

li + li{
  border-top: none;
}

/* Makeup */ li{width: 12rem;list-style: none;padding: .5rem 1rem;}
```

```html
<li>First</li>
<li>Second</li>
<li>Third</li>
<li>Fourth</li>
<li>Fifth</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

This thread is pretty old, but I found a new solution using the outline property. It works for vertical and horizontal lists, even if the horizontal list is multiple lines long.

Use a border of half the intended width, and add an outline also of half the intended width.

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0;
  /* also set the parent's padding to half of the intended border's width to prevent the outlines from overlapping anything they shouldn't overlap */
  padding: 0.5px;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-align: center;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;

  /* simulates a 1px-wide border */
  border: 0.5px solid black;
  outline: 0.5px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -6):

Give the elements margins. For example,

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Stuff</li>
    <li>Other Stuff</li>
<ul>
```

CSS:

```
li { border: 1px solid #000; margin: 5px 0; }
```

[jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/mhzfL/)

Comment: I'm doing this right now, but that is not solving the problem, just avoiding.