# simulate border collapse in horizontal ul li

Tags: css

I have a horizontal ul li, the li element gets a 1 pixel black border. Two adjacent elements gets a 2 pixel border because the border from the left and right elements gets merged.

Is there any tricks to simulate the table border-collapse property for solving this?

Comment: There are other ways to do this that do not involve "simulating" tables, such as first-child selectors. Does that work for you?

Comment: I'm not trying to simulate a table, I'm trying to simulate the table border-collapse property. I think I can use any other solutions for this (like using border in the left, and no border at the right, except the last child), but there is a nice little trick to do this in a vertical list (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737693/simulating-border-collapse-in-lists-no-tables) and I'm trying to find one for horizontal lists, maybe there is one around.

Comment: No border for ul. Margin-left/top of -1px for li. You might also have to make ul padding 2px. Refer to: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8417072/631764

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">A Link</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:
​

```
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    list-style:none
}

li {
    float:left;    
}    

​ul li a {
    display:block;
    padding:3px;
    border-top:1px solid #ff0000;   
    border-bottom:1px solid #ff0000; 
    border-right:1px solid #ff0000; 
}

ul li:first-child a {
    border-left:1px solid #ff0000
}
```