# List items without overlapping borders

Tags: html, css, html-lists, border

I have a `<ul>` that WOULD be dynamically added to using jQuery or whatnot. Each `<li>` would have a separate box around it, basically a selector.

However, I notice and anticipated that each `<li>`'s bottom border is overlapping with the next. Here's an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/gANNJ/

Is there a way to remove this? Should I just use separator divs instead?

Comment: What data will you be using in your `li` elements ? Only textual ?

Comment: Then you can use `table` with `border-collapse` proprety. For [example](http://jsfiddle.net/MA4qn/1).

Comment: I'd rather not use table. Are divs an option?

Comment: Check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5737768/1763929).

Comment: The second answer received more votes and it's Warai's answer. So I'll go with Warai's.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
li {
    margin-top: -1px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Cheap way of doing it ><.
They are not overlaping, its just 2px border from top and bottom

Comment: Good enough, I'll take it!

Answer (score 0):

use this i think this is work for u.

```css
li{
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-top: none;
   padding: 10px;
}
li:first-child {
   border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
  <li>list item </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: try this this is perfect for you. run in snippet and check

Answer (score -1):

You may try this

```
li {
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid;
    border-right:1px solid;
    padding: 10px;

}
li:first-child {
 border-top:1px solid black;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Comment: This adds too much of a separation. Thank you anyway!

Comment: you asked that it is overlapping so i added 1px which is the least separator.How you want it to display..

Comment: It's a visual issue. The border is 2x as thick while it should be 1x as think between each `<li>`

Comment: Check Warai's Answer above. How it is: http://jsfiddle.net/gANNJ/ how it is with Warai's answer: http://jsfiddle.net/gANNJ/7/