# How to make borders collapse (on a div)?

Tags: css

I have the outer div with `display: table; border-collapse: collapse;` and cells with `display: table-cell`. Why do they still not collapse?

There maybe variable number of cells in a column so I can't only have borders on one side.

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737693/simulating-border-collapse-in-lists-no-tables

Answer (score 47, accepted):

```css
.container {
  display: table;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

.column {
  display: table-row;
}

.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell">ddd</div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 113):

Use a simple negative margin rather than using `display: table`.

```css
.container {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  border-width: 1px 0 0 1px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px;
}

.clearfix {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column" style="background:red">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background:blue">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background:green">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background:yellow">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column" style="background:black">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 108):

Instead using `border` use `box-shadow`:

```
  box-shadow: 
    2px 0 0 0 #888, 
    0 2px 0 0 #888, 
    2px 2px 0 0 #888,   /* Just to fix the corner */
    2px 0 0 0 #888 inset, 
    0 2px 0 0 #888 inset;
```

Demo: http://codepen.io/Hawkun/pen/rsIEp

Comment: this is actually the best solution I have found. It sorts the problem if your data is dynamically generated and it doesn't guarantee perfect let's say 9 items in a grid, but instead 2 which if you have that with other solutions u get borders missing. Well done !

Comment: Good trick for responsive layouts, avoiding changing the display property.

Comment: This works fine for screen media. But on print media, box-shadow is considered as background and not printed.

Comment: This worked well for me, but notice that those first three shadows can be accomplished with:  


1px 1px 0 1px #888  


The spread and offset take care of the corners.

Comment: `box-shadow` is ignored (disappears) when using high contrast themes in Windows, so please always provide an alternative if you care about accessibility.

Comment: This is amazing. This is the only solution that works on elements that only overlap partly.

Answer (score 11):

Why not use `outline`? It is what you want:

```
outline: 1px solid red;
```

Here I show many variations of border collapsing. (using Bootstrap grid): https://codepen.io/leonardo1024/pen/KgbNGr

Answer (score 7):

You could also use negative margins:

```css
.column {
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 120px;
}
.cell {
  border: 1px solid red;
  width: 120px;
  height: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.cell:not(:first-child) {
  margin-top: -1px;
}
.column:not(:first-child) > .cell {
  margin-left: -1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
    <div class="cell"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I used the same method, just with `border-top/left: 0;`. Margins create offsets.

Comment: @toster-cx I suppose that's even better than overlapping the borders. Good thinking :-)

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `display: table-row` instead of `float: left;` to your column and obviously as @Hushme correct your `diaplay: table-cell` to `display: table-cell;`

```
 .container {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
.column {
    display: table-row;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 120px;
}
.cell {
    display: table-cell;
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 120px;
    height: 20px;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/R8eCr/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Example of using **border-collapse: separate;** as

container displayed as table:

```
ol[type="I"]>li{
  display: table;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 1rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use borders in pseudo-elements with margins & paddings.
It works with flex-wrap in multiple rows / cols.

```
.parent {
  display: flex; /* your container */
  flex-flow: column;

  position: relative;
  ::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 1px solid #424041; /* your border */
  }
  padding: 1px 0 0 1px; /* <border-width> 0 0 <border-width> */
}

.child{
  position: relative;
  ::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 1px solid #424041; /* your border */
  }
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; /* -<border-width> 0 0 -<border-width> */
}

.parentAndChild{
  display: flex; /* your container */
  flex-flow: row wrap;

  position: relative;
  ::before{
    content:'';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
    pointer-events: none;
    border: 1px solid #424041; /* your border */
  }
  margin: -1px 0 0 -1px; /* -<border-width> 0 0 -<border-width> */
  padding: 1px 0 0 1px; /* <border-width> 0 0 <border-width> */
}
```