# Nested divs: how can I get overlapping borders?

Tags: html, css

The following image shows the desired result:

[image: Desider result]

Below where I arrived using `position: relative`:

```
<div class="tags-container">
    <div class="tag">Pizza</div>
    <div class="tag">Spaghetti</div>
    <div class="tag">Mandolino</div>
    <div class="tag">Pizza</div>
    <div class="tag">Spaghetti</div>
    <div class="tag">Mandolino</div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

```css
.tags-container {   
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    width: 300px;
}
.tag {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}
```

http://www.lucagiorcelli.it/test/testing-borders.html

Comment: Maybe you could check this out? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915865/how-to-make-borders-collapse-on-a-div

Comment: @KurtUXD Just updated the answer to fit your needs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

<s>You could reset top/left `border` to `0` and use `top` property an a negative value for `margin-top` to achieve the result</s>.

Actually, there's **no** need to use reset the borders.

While *relative [positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position)* reserves space in the flow to prevent changing the layout, *margin* moves the element literally.

Thus you could add a negative top/left `margin` to the `.tag` elements. However [there will be an extra border](http://jsbin.com/lemic/1/edit) at the bottom of the elements in the last row.

In order to shift the border up, you could append a dummy child into the `.tags-container` and use a negative bottom `margin` for that element.

Since you are using a `<div>` element at the end of the `.tags-container` to clearing the float, you could apply the needed negative margin to that element as well.

```
<div class="tags-container">
  <div class="tag">Pizza</div>
  <div class="tag">Spaghetti</div>
  <!-- other .tag elements... -->
  <div style="clear: both"></div> <!-- Apply negative margin to this element -->
</div>
```

```css
.tag {
  float: left;
  margin-top: -1px;
  margin-left: -1px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ff0000;
}

.tags-container div:last-child {
  margin-bottom: -1px; /* This negative margin overlaps the bottom border */
}
```

**[WORKING DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lemic/2/edit)**.

---

Alternatively, you could use [`::after`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3a%3aafter) pseudo element as the last child of the `.tags-container` to clear the float and apply the negative margin:

```css
.tags-container:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}
```

**[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsbin.com/lemic/3/edit)**.

Comment: Me hat's off to your guvnor!

Comment: The only case this doesn't work is when a row is longer than the previous... http://jsfiddle.net/mendesjuan/ZpwxH/ If you omit the bottom borders instead you fix that case and break the original :)

Comment: If you set the width of the container to 100, it does not give the expected result.

Comment: Yes there are some limits, I'll update the answer If I could find a better approach.

Comment: @HashemQolami That seems to do it for me, the shifted borders overlap. Pretty nice! I think your second selector would be more accurate as `.tags-container .tag:last-child`

Comment: @HashemQolami This is resolutive (and elegant).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative using a bit of hacks.

[fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/pwvR6/)

```
<style>
  .tags-container {     
    border-top: 1px solid #ff0000;
    border-right: 1px solid #ff0000;
    border-left: 1px solid #ff0000;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .tag {
    float: left;
    top: -1px;
    left: -1px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #ff0000;
    margin-left:-1px;
    margin-top:-1px;
  }
  .bottomBorderHack{
    margin-top:-1px;
    border-bottom:1px green solid;
    width: 100%;
  }
</style>

<div style="width:10%;">
    <div class="tags-container">
        <div class="tag">Pizza</div>
        <div class="tag">Spaghetti</div>
        <div class="tag">Mandolino</div>
        <div class="tag">Pizza</div>
        <div class="tag">Spaghetti</div>
        <div class="tag">Mandolino</div>
        <div class="tag">Mandolino</div>
        <div style="clear: both"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="bottomBorderHack"></div>
</div>
```

Note, I used a green border-bottom so it's more visible. Also, your browser need to support box-sizing if you dont want to specify `.bottomBorderHack` and `.tags-container` width.

Comment: Thanks! The hack works on known container width (e.g. width: 100px). But can I make the hack working with unknown width (e.g. width: 100%)?

Comment: Updated the answer ^^