# Collapse borders between two floating divs?

Tags: html, css

so i am having trouble collapsing borders between two floating divs.  I know how to do it with table cells but these are not cells and I'm not using tables.  Here is a picture of what the picture looks like [page image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JvX6A.png)

Here is my html and css code as well.

```css
body{
background-color: #C8C8C8;
}

h1{
    text-shadow: 2px 3px gray;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 200px;
 }

 img.width{
    width: 100%;
  }

  img.tLeft {
    float: left;
    z-index: -1;
    padding-right: 3em;
  }

  img.tRight {
    float: right;
    z-index: -1;
  }


 .div1 {
    width: 900px;
    height: 700px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #A8A8A8;
    background-color: #4dffa6;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -1;
    }

    .div2 {
     height: auto;
     border: 1px solid red;
     overflow: hidden;
      border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    float: left;
    border-right: collapse;
    }

   .div3 {
    height: auto;
      border: 1px solid red;
     overflow: hidden;
     border-top-right-radius: 20px;
     top: 0;
     right: 0;
     z-index: -1;
     float: right;

     }

 .div4 {
   height: auto;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    background-color: lightgray;
    overflow: hidden;
    left: 0;
    display: block;
}

 strong{
    font-size: 70px;
    color: red;
  }
```

```html
<div>
 <img class="width" src="images/rancidbanner.png" alt="Rancid Tomatoes">
</div>

<h1>TMNT (2015)</h1>

<!---block one--->
<div class="div1">

    <!---block two--->
    <div class="div2">
    <img class="tLeft" src="images/rottenlarge.png" alt="Rotten" /> <strong>33%</strong>
    </div>

    <!---block three--->
    <div class="div3">
    <img class="tRight" src="images/overview.png" alt="general overview" />
    </div>

    <!---box four
    <div class="div4">
    <p>HEllo relkgnaldfkgnadlgsknasdlkgnasldkgnaslkdgnasldkn aslkdgnslkdgn sjdnaslkdjfnaslkdjfn sdgnaslkjgnlaskjgdn
    </p>
    </div>
    --->
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915865/how-to-make-borders-collapse-on-a-div

Comment: Only tables provide the native ability to collapse borders between cells; since you aren't using tables, you must not put borders where you don't want them!

Answer (score 0):

Might be worth using a CSS reset so that the browser doesn't affect your CSS - http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2011/01/03/reset-revisited/

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.