# Set divs with overlapping borders

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there an easy way to overlap borders on `div`s?

Say you have this:

```css
.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
<div class='box'></div>
```

You can see a "double border" where the `div`s meetup.
I want to show only a single `1px` border between `div`s.

I know you can set different classes, but was wondering about an easier solution.

**why is my question different**
well I dont have a container wrapped arounf the divs. So according to that answer the `border-collapse:collapse` have to be applied to the parent or wrapper element.

Comment: This might not be the best, or "correct", way of doing it, but nothing prevents you from setting div #2 to having a margin-top of -1px.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make borders collapse (on a div)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915865/how-to-make-borders-collapse-on-a-div)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have a couple of options via CSS. You could do this:

```
.box + .box {
    margin-top: -1px;
}
```

Or

```
.box + .box {
    border-top-width: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this code

```
<div class="container">
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
  <div class='box'></div>
</div>


.box {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-bottom: -1px;
}

.box:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

live demo - https://jsfiddle.net/8cc8hoxf/