# Make single border of multiple divs with borders

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

[image: gif]

All the elements are draggable (jquery-ui) with a [snap](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#snap-to) function.

Every div has a border, so if two div's are aside of each other it will have a double border. In the snap function of jquery-ui you can see which div's are snapping to each other but not on which side.

How can I check which div's are colliding so I can remove the border of 1 div so it will be a single border between the div's?

Comment: What is the question? Please edit the question title because there isn't a clear question.

Comment: You should share your code, we can't do anything without it.

Comment: The border is an part of the DIv and thus has rendering. You could add `margin: -1px;` where the number of negative pixels is equal to the border of the div. This will allow the border to exist yet not be part of the collision.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915865/how-to-make-borders-collapse-on-a-div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this adjusting each `<DIV>` to display as part of a table. It's a little complex. As mentioned, you can adjust to just using `margin: -1px;` I also very much like the `box-shadow` suggestion. An example:

```js
$(function() {
  $(".drag").draggable({
    containment: "parent",
    handle: ".drag-handle",
    snap: true
  });
  $(".drag-handle").each(function(ind, el) {
    var $par = $(el).parent();
    $(el).position({
      my: "right top",
      at: "right-5 top+5",
      of: $par
    });
  });
});
```

```css
.canvas {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 440px;
  height: 300px;
}

.drag {
  /*
  border: 1px solid #000;
  */
  box-shadow: 1px 0px #000, 0px 1px #000, 1px 1px #000, 1px 0px #000 inset, 0px 1px #000 inset;
  float: left;
}

.drag label {
  margin: 2px;
}

.drag .drag-handle {
  border-radius: 6px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<div class="canvas ui-widget">
  <div id="item-1" class="drag" style="width: 100%; height: 90px;">
    <label>DIV 1</label>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4 drag-handle"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="item-2" class="drag" style="width: 50%; height: 60px;">
    <label>DIV 2</label>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4 drag-handle"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="item-3" class="drag" style="width: 50%; height: 60px;">
    <label>DIV 3</label>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4 drag-handle"></span>
  </div>
  <div id="item-4" class="drag" style="width: 100%; height: 80px;">
    <label>DIV 4</label>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrow-4 drag-handle"></span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Adapted from an answer seen here: [How to make borders collapse (on a div)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915865/how-to-make-borders-collapse-on-a-div)

Comment: Yes this is it, but there is a double border on the left side. The other sides are completely perfect!

Comment: @MarcelWeidum could do the same with the outer box. Or `padding: -1px;`