# <div> border collapse not quite collapsing

Tags: css

I have a little widget of adjacent divs created by angular ng-repeat.

It looks like this (vertical borders except for forst & last look like they are 2px which suggests border-collapse isn't collapsing:

[image]

What I want it to look like is this, except with a left border on the first box.  (css specifies no left border)

[image] .

I can of course, set a `border-style: solid` on just the first box to get a left border, but I am creating these widgets programatically with AngularJs which means I would have to right logic to have different css on the first widget than the other 7.  But it seems like I should be able to get what I need with the same css on all the divs if collapse worked as expected.

Here's current CSS I used with all the little tricks I saw in various posts on the subject to avoid the double vertical border.

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin-left: 5px;
}
.item  {
   display: table-cell;
   border: 1px solid gray;
   border-spacing: 0px;
   border-left-style: none;
   background-color:  #fffff7;
   border-collapse: collapse;
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: For CSS questions, can I suggest you make a CodePen so people can play with it?

Comment: Please attach the HTML in addition to the CSS

Comment: related to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17915865/how-to-make-borders-collapse-on-a-div

Comment: `border-collapse` applies only to `table` and `inline-table`. https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#borders

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`border-collapse` doesn't do anything to table-cell styled elements, it's used with `display:table`.

Your code looks this way because you are applying a `1px` wide border to every element, causing them to stack next to eachother and become `2px`.

Because you didn't supply HTML I create something simple, but this should give you an idea of how you could handle borders if you want to use flex-box.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin-left: 5px;
}
.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  border-left: 0;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  background-color:  #fffff7;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

.container > div:first-child{
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div>O</div>
  <div>O</div>
  <div>O</div>
  <div>O</div>
  <div>O</div>
  <div>O</div>
  <div>O</div>
  <div>O</div>
</div>
```

P.S. You should probably use grid for this instead of flexbox

Comment: Thanks.  Forgot about first-child selector.  That will likely be the solution.