# Bootstrap 3: Wrong border height inside grid

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am working with bootstrap 3 grid system and would like to create a border between two grid columns.

This here is my code:

```
<div class="row">    
    <div class="col-lg-2" style="border-right:1px solid #CCC">
       some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10">
       more content<br />more content<br />more content
    </div>
</div>
```

The border between the columns will only be as high as the left column, not as high as the full row. I'd like it to extend to the full row height, just like in a real `<table>`.

Have a look at this example:

[image: Example]

The second part of the image is what I'd like to achieve.

Any Idea how to solve that problem?

Answer (score 2):

You could add a new class to remove the space and apply it to each row but you should look into replacing your col classes with row classes because they have no natural padding.

```
.nopad {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because its two separated blocks with owns height, so you must apply border color for highest block.

```
<div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-lg-2">
       some content
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-10" style="border-left:1px solid #CCC">
       more content<br />more content<br />more content
    </div>
</div>
```

Or you can make the same hight for all block using javascript.
Or you can try make grid by flexbox.

Comment: Problem is that I do not know which one will be the highest box. I will not have these lines for all of my grids

Answer (score 0):

The challenge with using the border is that it is controlled by the box model.  Assuming that you want to work with the left div's right border, the height of that border will be controlled by the height of the div itself.  When the left div is taller than the right, the vertical separator will look correct.  When the left div is shorter than the right, the vertical separator won't be long enough.  The is because the box on the right is taller than the box on the left.

The way to deal with it (I think, as I have not tested it in this particular case) is to set the height style of the left div to 100%.  That way it expands to fill the parent box, if the right div is the taller of the two.  This may require you to set the vertical-align style to keep the content positioned correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You can just add left & right borders to all columns, so the tallest column will dictate the visible border height.

Since this will effectively double your border-width (partially), you'll also need to collapse them. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/8417072/2795627 :

```
.row > div {
    border-left: 1px;
    border-right: 1px;
    margin-left: -1px;
    margin-top: -1px; /* optional, for top and bottom borders */
    box-sizing: border-box; /* prevent columns from wrapping due to exceeded row width */
}
```